# Excel 2011 VBA - Set Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am puzzled by how Range() works.

I have the following code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ShowRange()
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = WorkSheets(1).Range("B:D")
End Sub
```

I noticed that rng returns D as column number 4. Shouldn't it return as column number 3?

Bregs,
Yakult121

Comment: I believe Excel defines the range based on the entire workssheet so your range of B:D means 2-4  thus column A would be 1.

Comment: Hi xQbert, ok i see. I was used to OpenOffice's Range object. I thought worksheet will be partitioned and rng will have just three columns i.e. B, C, D

Answer (score 4):

The `Column` property is a global, sheet-wide column number of the cell.

If `rng = WorkSheets(1).Range("B:D")`, then column D is `rng.Columns(3)`, because D is the third column in `rng`. But `rng.Columns(3).Column` is `4`.